# How can I make the openIE input file format

Tags: nlp, tuples, information-extraction, allennlp

I want to do OpenIE extraction and make the input file, but I cannot figure out the way to convert the raw sentence. My example is below:

Example(input raw sentence):

```
32.7 % of all households were made up of individuals and 15.7 % had someone living alone who was 65 years of age or older .
```

output:

```
32.7 % of all households were made up of individuals and 15.7 % had someone living alone who was 65 years of age or older . were made up of 32.7 % of all households    individuals

32.7 % of all households were made up of individuals and 15.7 % had someone living alone who was 65 years of age or older . had 15.7 % of all households    someone living alone who was 65 years of age or older
```

I know that the output file is the extracted one but I cannot find the code or the way to convert like output sentences

Is there any method to do so?

Please help!

I've already tried Ollie and OpenIE-5 but the output format is not that I want

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to do? Do you want to simply perform OpenIE on your example (input raw sentence) and produce some results where the format matches the output you've listed? Or are you after the specific output you've provided (i.e. both the content and format)?

Comment: I want to produce some results where the format just matches the output one. For example, like the first sentence of the output, join the original sentence ("32.7 % of all households were made up of individuals and 15.7 % had someone living alone who was 65 years of age or older .") + and extracted verb and object ("were made up of 32.7 % of all households    individuals")